# No account on emulator

Tags: android

I am working on an contacts app, thanks to sample provided in android SDK. As in the sample provided, contact can be added only to accounts present on the device. they mentioned in the documentation that they prohibit the contact insertion in case of no account. On the emulator, There is not a single account, on the other hand, there should be at least one for holding the phone contacts. my query is that on real device, is it possible for my app to meet such devices with no accounts, not even for phone contacts.

And in such case, do I need to insert null in name and type and move on ?

Comment: Sure. Take a factory-fresh device and walk through the initial set-up, skipping the Google Account step. I do that all the time in testing, and we distribute devices all ready, except for the account.

Comment: Ok. to add an contact in that case, do I place a null in name and type and insert the contact ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached to a conclusion here.
An application can definitly meet such devices where no acoounts are present to hold the contact realted data. In that case, one can use null in each account name and account type to continue. Here is the code snippet that decides which account type and acount name would hold the newly created contact.

```
ops.add(
                ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, acc_name)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, type)
                .build());
```

One can put `null` in each of the `ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE` but the ideal thing to do would be to provide user a list of available accounts and let user select the account he wants. One thing needsd to be remembered in this situation too, you can't edit all the contacts like facebook contacts.

Hope it does help somebody else.